# Check all possible connection exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check for all connections between two table exists and return all rows specifying weather the connections exists or not for example here is my tables:

Permissions:

| index | Controller | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Error | index |
| 2 | Home | index |
| 3 | Home | login |
| 4 | Home | logout |
| 1 | Test | index |
| 9 | UserManagement | createUser |
| 8 | UserManagement | editUser |
| 6 | UserManagement | index |

Roles_Permissions:

| Roles | Permissions |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 |

Roles:

| Role_id | Role_name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Admin |
| 2 | special |
| 3 | User |
| 1 | Visitor |

if the query variable is **Special** I want following rows returned:

| index | Controller | Action | Exist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Error | index | yes |
| 2 | Home | index | yes |
| 3 | Home | login | yes |
| 4 | Home | logout | yes |
| 1 | Test | index | yes |
| 9 | UserManagement | createUser | no |
| 8 | UserManagement | editUser | no |
| 6 | UserManagement | index | no |

Foreign key exists between `role_id` and `perm_id`

Comment: Welcome to Snack OverGnome. Please read [**How to format my code**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and then edit your code displayed above . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need something like this

```
SET @role_name = 'special';

SELECT 
    p.*,
    IF(ISNULL(rp.role_id), 'no', 'yes') AS exist
FROM permissions p
LEFT JOIN roles_permissions rp ON rp.permission_id = p.id AND rp.role_id = (
    SELECT role_id FROM roles WHERE role_name = @role_name
)
```

Output

| id | controller | action | exist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Error | index | yes |
| 2 | Home | index | yes |
| 3 | Home | login | yes |
| 4 | Home | logout | yes |
| 1 | Test | index | yes |
| 9 | UserManagement | createUser | no |
| 8 | UserManagement | editUser | no |
| 6 | UserManagement | index | no |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d73d345c9efccc9063d2728662c154e)

Comment: Can we do alter based on return table. Say I want to alter the roleperm table to show user management->index to yes and test->index to no, through similar SQL query?